# StandardizedVector returned by FeatureExtract/FeatureExtraction is not the same as Standardize

Tags: data, machine-learning

The documentation would suggest that the "StandardizedVector" option of [FeatureExtract](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FeatureExtract.html) and  [FeatureExtraction](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FeatureExtraction.html) should give the same results as [Standardize](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Standardize.html) ("numeric data processed with Standardize"), but they are not numerically identical:

```
example = RandomReal[{100, 125}, 1000];
example[[1 ;; 5]]
(* {110.711, 107.838, 119.151, 110.001, 107.939} *)


(*compare the effects of the two approaches*)
Take[#, 5]& @ Standardize[example]
(* {-0.246331, -0.64833, 0.934736, -0.345705, -0.634303} *)

Take[#, 5]& @ Flatten @ FeatureExtract[example, "StandardizedVector"]
(* {-0.246454, -0.648655, 0.935204, -0.345878, -0.634621} *)
```

**What's going on here?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two methods differ in how they [interpret the variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Population_variance_and_sample_variance). Namely, `Standardize` uses the *sample* variance (where you divide by $n-1$), and `FeatureExtract` uses the *population* variance (where you divide by $n$).

Let me convince you with a simpler example:

```
list = {-1., 0., 1.};

list1 = Standardize[list]
(* {-1., 0., 1.} *) 
list2 = Flatten@FeatureExtract[list, "StandardizedVector"]
(* {-1.22474, 0., 1.22474} *)

StandardDeviation[list1]
(* 1. *)
StandardDeviation[list2]
(* 1.22474 *)

popStandardDeviation[list_] := Sqrt[Total[(list - Mean[list])^2]/Length[list]]
popStandardDeviation[list1]
(* 0.816497 *)
popStandardDeviation[list2]
(* 1. *)
```

You see,  `FeatureExtract` did standardize the list, but in such a way that the *population* variance is 1. I certainly agree with you that the description in documentation for [`FeatureExtract`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FeatureExtract.html) is misleading. Consider reporting it to the WRI.